# Is there a way to get the metrics from a kafka server remotely in a c# program?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, jmx

My current project in c# requires getting the number of under replicated partitions from a kafka server. I can view this in jconsole under the mbeans section, but I need to get the value in a c# program. I tried using NetMX with this code to make the initial connection.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
INetMXConnector connector = NetMXConnectorFactory.Connect(new Uri("http://<myserver>:<jmxport>"), null);    
IMBeanServerConnection remoteServer = connector.MBeanServerConnection;
```

A "Section not found" error is thrown at the second line and I was wondering if anyone could help with this please?

Comment: It was not in .net, but I used jolokia for some basic monitoring and it works ok.

Never tried INetMXConnector, but looking at github code, your error comes that you need an App.Config for it to work - see samples here
https://github.com/SzymonPobiega/NetMX/tree/master/Samples/JmxClientDemo

https://github.com/SzymonPobiega/NetMX/blob/master/NetMX.Default/MBeanServer.cs#L36

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NetMX will connect to a Java JMX endpoint. It's an "independent" implementation specifically for DotNet.

Your best bet is to load the [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) java-agent into your target Kafka servers. Jolokia exposes JMX via an HTTP/REST interface which you can access via C#.

You could try [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/) (a java byte code to CLR which will provide you a Java JMX compatible DLL you can invoke against. IKVM is a compiler that converts Java byte code to .NET byte code. The standard JMX remoting works fine from a C# client.

Comment: Hey, so I installed the Jolokia war agent into the webapp folder of tomcat. However when i make requests to get the kafka metrics, it gives an error. Furthermore, I used the list request and that also did not show anything about kafka, but it does show the standard java stuff like "java.lang". However, when I use jconsole on my computer to connect to the jmx port on the server, I can see all the kafka metrics. Have you come across this before?

Comment: I would use the jolokia java agent instead of the war.

Comment: I tried running this as stated in the documentation: java -javaagent:jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=7777,host=localhost
I get this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7777 host=localhost"
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed. I have left out most of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your Jolokia configuration, perhaps you need to fully qualify the path of the jar. Mine looks like this and works:

```
export JOLOKIA_HOME=/libs/java/jolokia/1.3.7
export JOLOKIA_JAR=$JOLOKIA_HOME/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar
export KAFKA_OPTS="-javaagent:$JOLOKIA_JAR=port=7778,host=* $KAFKA_OPTS"
```

When I start Kafka in non-daemon mode, it prints this:

```
I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://10.8.36.121:7778/jolokia/
```

Then I point my browser to http://localhost:7778/jolokia/search/*:* and I get:

```
{
  "request": {
    "mbean": "*:*",
    "type": "search"
  },
  "value": [
    "kafka.network:name=ResponseQueueTimeMs,request=ListGroups,type=RequestMetrics",
    "kafka.server:delayedOperation=topic,name=PurgatorySize,type=DelayedOperationPurgatory",
    "kafka.server:delayedOperation=Fetch,name=NumDelayedOperations,type=DelayedOperationPurgatory",
    "kafka.network:name=RemoteTimeMs,request=Heartbeat,type=RequestMetrics",
<-- SNIP -->
    "kafka.network:name=LocalTimeMs,request=Offsets,type=RequestMetrics"
  ],
  "timestamp": 1504188793,
  "status": 200
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually running kafka on a windows server. So I set up an environment variable for "KAKFA_OPS" and restarted kafka yet it still does not work. Do I need to have something else to run the agent jar? FYI I have the JRE installed

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `jolokia` jar to convert `JMX` to `HTTP` by adding:

> KAFKA_OPTS: javaagent:/usr/share/java/kafka/jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/var/private/sasl_acl/kafka.server.jaas.config.

2) You will get a http endpoint now you can try a sample get request to check whether it works
http://localhost:8778/jolokia/read//java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage

3) Use standard rest api libraries to consume above endpoint.