# Kafka Connect - metrics through JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am using confluent HDFS sink connector and would like to know how to get consumer properties to expose through either JMX or REST API.

I checked the following two properties, however, I don't know how to expose metrics to jmx port

1. connect-standalone.properties
2. consumer.properties

Comment: If you want to use REST, then use Jolokia and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984363/2308683

Answer (score 3):

Set `JMX_PORT` when you launch Kafka Connect. e.g.

```
export JMX_PORT=4242
./bin/connect-distributed ./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties
```

You can then connect to JMX using JConsole, JMXTerm, etc.

Comment: I modified the file `./bin/connect-distributed` and mentioned the port inside it `JMX_PORT=4242` and then restarted the service. However it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a few days back - this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835399/is-there-a-way-to-configure-kafka-connect-jmx-metrics-to-be-captured-using-a-jmx) has one way how the issue was resolved. It was able to expose the metrics using jmx exporter, which got scraped by Prometheus.