# Is there a way to configure kafka-connect jmx metrics to be captured using a jmx_exporter/prometheus?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect, jmx-exporter

I'm setting up monitoring for Kafka connect in our Kafka ecosystem. I have enabled JMX exporter for kafka brokers and is working fine. Now I am trying to enable JMX exporter for kafka connect. However, it is a bit unclear where to start.

I can only modify `connect-distributed.sh` to enable the change. Any pointers would be a great addition.

`kafka-run-class.sh` was modified to enable `jmx_exporter` to emit jmx metrics on `http://<host>:9304/metrics`

I expect kafka-connect to emit metrics on `http://<host>:19000/metrics` once the `jmx_exporter` has been enabled.

Answer (score 7):

Modifying a script in the `bin` directory is highly unrecommended. When upgrading Kafka to the next version, extracting the new binaries would override the changes made in the script.

The preferred way should be to set the environment variable `KAFKA_JMX_OPTS` outside the script:

> export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-javaagent:/opt/kafka/libs/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=127.0.0.1:10902:/etc/kafka-connect/jmx_exporter.yaml"

If the var is set before starting Kafka via the script it will use the var instead of the default values defined in `/bin/kafka-server-start.sh`

This answer is inspered by [**How do I set the Java options for Kafka**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36649296/7109598)?

Comment: It should also be added to this solution that the jar needs to be in classpath

Answer (score 0):

Digging around I have found a solution to the issue. Java agent can be added to the `connect-distributed.sh` and starts to emit the metrics nicely.

So enable `jmx_exporter` on Kafka Connect framework

1. Open `connect-distributed.sh`
2. Modify the last line which calls the `kafka-run-class.sh`

```
exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed "$@"
```

to the following

```
exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS -javaagent:/path/to/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=9408:/path/to/config/file/prometheus.yml org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed "$@"
```

Comment: Good question, but controversial answer - sorry for downvoting

Comment: Adding Apm agent jar in the same way above.. worked well  !! thanks